# How to compare inner array key and values and set the value of variable accordingly in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've a following big array called `$UserProfile` as follows :

```
Array
(
[cf_classification] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 10
            [field_name] => classification
            [customValue] => 11
            [cg_user_group_id] => 0
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Freshman
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Shopomore
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Junior
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Senior
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Masters
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Ph.D
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Now if you see from the above array there is one key-value pair as follows :

```
[customValue] => 11
```

In above array also there is one inner level array called `options` as follows :

```
[options] => Array
                    (
                        [11] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => Freshman
                            )

                        [12] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => Shopomore
                            )

                        [13] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => Junior
                            )

                        [14] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => Senior
                            )

                        [15] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => Masters
                            )

                        [16] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => Ph.D
                            )

                    )
```

What I want to achieve is compare the values of keys of **inner array** options with the value of key  `[customValue]` from **outer array** and upon match is found assign the value to the new variable `$education`.

In short in above case $education should have value `'Freshman'` since 11 is the matching key and value. So the desired output would be

```
$educaion = 'Freshman';
```

My question is how to do it programmatically by making minimum number of comparisons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this could give you some idea

i make use of the method the array_keys_exists($key, $array)
to check if this key is existing on the array

you can check out this also
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

```
<?php


$user_profile = array(
    'cf_classification' => array(
        'field_id' => 10,
        'field_name' => 'classification',
        'customValue' => 11,
        'cg_user_group_id' => 0,
        'options' => array(
                11 => array(
                        'value' => 'Freshman'
                    ),

                12 => array(
                        'value' => 'Shopomore'
                    ),

                13 => array(
                        'value' => 'Junior'
                    ),

                14 => array(
                        'value' => 'Senior'
                    ),

            15 => array(
                        'value' => 'Masters'
                    ),

        16 => array(
                        'value' => 'Ph.D'
                    )

            )

    )
);


$custom_field = $user_profile['cf_classification']['customValue'];
$education = '';
$options = $user_profile['cf_classification']['options'];
# check if the $custom_field is in the options of user_profile['cf_classification']
# using the array_key_exist method

if (array_key_exists($custom_field, $options)) {
    # to get the value of the custom field then you need to traverse
    # the array for its value
    $education = $options[$custom_field]['value'];
} else {
    $education =  "not found";
}

echo $education;
```

this will print

```
Freshman
```